# How to interpret situations where Math.Acos() reports invalid input?

Tags: c#, math, vector, trigonometry, nan

Hey all.  I'm computing the angle between two vectors, and sometimes Math.Acos() returns NaN when it's input is out of bounds (-1 > input && input > 1) for a cosine.  What does that mean, exactly?  Would someone be able to explain what's happening?  Any help is appreciated!

Here's my method:

```
 public double AngleBetween(vector b)
    {
        var dotProd = this.Dot(b);
        var lenProd = this.Len*b.Len;
        var divOperation = dotProd/lenProd;

        //  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.acos.aspx
        return Math.Acos(divOperation) * (180.0 / Math.PI);
    }
```

Here's my implementation of `Dot` and `Len`:

```
public double Dot(vector b)
    {
        // x's and y's are lattitudes and longitudes (respectively)
        return ( this.From.x*b.From.x + this.From.y*b.From.y);
    }

    public double Len{
        get
        {
             // geo is of type SqlGeography (MS SQL 2008 Spatial Type) with an SRID of 4326
             return geo.STLength().Value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: nitpick: the out-of-bounds condition should be written: `(-1 > input || input > 1)`, or even `!(-1 <= input && input <= 1)`.

Comment: But a (latitude, longitude) pair isn't a 2D vector, they are angle measurements in 3D.  So what are you trying to find?  Perhaps the internal angle at the center of the earth or the bearing between the two?  This formula isn't going to get you either.

Comment: Also, what is 'From'?  For a 2D Vector object you'd expect it to contain x and y values and for the Dot method to be just this.X * other.X + this.Y * other.Y.  You'd also expect the Len method to just return sqrt(x*x + y*y) not some some value calculated from something else entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have vectors for which `divOperation` turns out to be < -1 or > 1? Then I think you should check your implementations of `Dot` and `Len`.

Comment: I've added dot and len to the question.  Take a look and tell me what you think.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed it.  I've left out a crucial piece of the dot() method.

Comment: @Sean can you post an explanation of what that crucial piece was, for those of us that might be curious?

Comment: Basically, I left out the To.X & To.Y parts of the dot product... Me.Smart == spotty.... LOL.

Answer (score 2):

Since the Cos of an angle is always between -1 and +1 there is no way to compute the inverse function (Acos) of a value outside that range OR it means you passed NaN to the ACos function.

I suspect in this case it's the latter - one of your lengths is probably zero.

Answer (score 0):

[NaN means "not a number"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN). Mathematically, you can't take the arccosine of a number that is outside the range [-1, 1] (or maybe you can but the result is complex -- I don't remember) so the result of trying to do that is not any number at all.

Comment: So, what does that say about the two vectors and their respective directions?

Comment: Good question. Can you provide a couple of samples of vectors for which it fails?